# C# VS2010 program compiling + running on Linux MONO

Tags: c#, mono

I have a c# program I wrote. I want to run it on Mono on CentOS 6.  What are the steps I need to take to compile it?  I read some steps using xbuild which I could not get to work, some steps using gmcs, etc.  Nothing working right now.

A simple and to the point guide would be good. I ran it through a Mono Analyzer and it did not give any errors for Mono, so it should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Well you shouldn't have to special compile it at all as long as it doesn't have a GUI (meaning it's just a console app), or that GUI is a simple Windows Forms or GTK#. Mono will run a regular C# program on the console just fine.  There is some quirkiness with Windows Forms, which was never fully finished, but generally you should just be able to compile using VS 2010, copy the dll's and executables to the system you want to run it on, and run 'mono myprogram.exe'. We run several older programs we have this way.

Comment: Thank you but now I keep getting

  at LKCamelot.io.IOThread.run () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at LKCamelot.io.IOThread.run () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0

Is there a way to diagnose this?

Comment: I think i may need to compile the program under mono

Comment: You don't. Mono is an open source .Net runtime. The problem is with your code or you are using some library that Mono doesn't support. Is LKCamelot your project? I can't find anything about that. Are you running multi-thread?

Comment: I have a static method that does World world = new World(); world.Tick();  << Throws here a:

A type load exception has occured.   (I got rid of the filename unknown exception by removing all references to unsupporteed libraries)

Answer (score 0):

To run a .net program under mono all you have to do is to copy the .exe file with all depending dlls to the mono machine and run the application with:

```
mono myprogram.exe
```

if this doesn't work, something with your code doesn't work with mono/Linux.

As you mentioned in a comment, you got some IO errors, that could be because you trying to connect to COM1 or something like that. COM doesn't exist in Linux, as I'm sure other stuff doesn't either (I'm a very beginner with Linux ^^).

Maybe you should try to Console.WriteLine() at some points off your code. That's a good way to "debug" without debugger ^^